How to set GTM regex for page view
I'm trying to get page view for all products pages with Google Tag Manager.
I need to activate the page view only for some url's with this format:
www.mysite.com/collection/type/category

where type and category are dynamics.
So i have set an activator with this property:
 Page Path is \/collection\/[^\/]+\/[a-z0-9-]+$

If i test this with regex101.com and is correct but with debug mode my event is not fired.

type is matched by anything but category specifically lowercase only... so it may depend on what type/category you actually have

category is only lowercase. But when i use on GTM the event is not fired even if the path mathes with this regex

open GTM preview and inspect your tag  on the event of your trigger. See why it doesn't fire. If it's indeed regex, then go to variables and see what the value of your Page Path variable on the event in question. take it and test the regex in the console or somewhere like regex101.
